# A and B flip a fair dice until 6 occurs. What's the expectation of flipping conditioned on A wins?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A and B flip a fair dice until 6 occurs. What's the expectation of flipping conditioned on A wins.

My solution is to calculate it by

$$\begin{align*}E(6\text{ occurs}) &= E(E(6 \text{ occurs}|A \text{ wins})) \\[0.3cm] &= E(6 \text{ occurs}|A \text{ wins}) \cdot P(A \text{ wins}) + E(6 \text{ occurs}|B \text{ wins}) \cdot P(B \text{ wins})
\end{align*}$$

For $P(A \text{ wins})$, it's simply

$$P(A \text{ wins}) = 1/6 + 5/6 \cdot (1-P(A \text{ wins}))=6/11$$

However, how to tackle $E(6 \text{ occurs}|B \text{ wins})$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a near-symmetry to the game: If $A$ rolls anything other than $6$, then we think about the rest of the game starting from the second roll as the beginning of a brand new game where $B$ is going first.

Answer (score 3):

I’ll write $X$ for the number of rolls (since “$6$ occurs” sounds more like an event than a random variable).

Conditional on $B$ winning, $A$’s first roll is irrelevant, since it’s known not to be a $6$. After that roll, $B$ goes first, so the expected number of the remaining rolls conditional on $B$ winning is simply $\mathsf E[X\mid\text{A wins}]$. Thus, $\mathsf E[X\mid\text{B wins}]=1+\mathsf E[X\mid\text{A wins}]$, and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E[X]
&=&
\mathsf P(\text{A wins})\mathsf E[X|\text{A wins}]+\mathsf P(\text{B wins})\mathsf E[X|\text{B wins}]
\\
&=&
\frac6{11}\mathsf E[X|\text{A wins}]+\frac5{11}(1+\mathsf E[X|\text{A wins}])
\\
&=&
E[X|\text{A wins}]+\frac5{11}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

So

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[X|\text{A wins}]
&=&
\mathsf E[X]-\frac5{11}
\\
&=&
6-\frac5{11}
\\
&=&
5\frac6{11}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}