# A and B flip a fair dice until 6 occurs. Why was my calculation wrong?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

A and B flip a fair dice until 6 occurs. I have read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859742/a-and-b-flip-a-fair-dice-until-6-occurs-whats-the-expectation-of-flipping-cond) and tried to work out the expectation of flipping on A wins. But it seems something goes wrong. Following is my work:

A wins iff $6$ occurs in odd round, so the EXP flippings on A wins is therefore:
$$E = \frac{1}{6}*1 + (\frac{5}{6})^2*\frac{1}{6}*3+....(\frac{5}{6})^{2k}*\frac{1}{6}*(2k+1)+...$$
It is straightforward to get $E=\frac{366}{121}$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: You must divide by the probability that $A$ wins (to handle the conditioning), which is $\frac 6{11}$, and $\frac {366}{121}\times \frac {11}6=\frac {61}{11}$ as desired.

Comment: I have also noticed this , but why do I need to divide by the probability that A
 wins? A wins iff 6 occurs in odd round, am i wrong?@lulu

Comment: That's what conditioning is.  $P(X\,|\,Y)=\frac {P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$.  You only compute the numerator.    Suppose, that $A's$ payout was $100$  upon victory, and $0$ upon loss.  Then  $A's$ expected payout conditioned on victory is $100$, clearly.  But your calculation would just return $100\times P(A)$, which is $A's$ unconditioned expected payout.

Comment: I understand your example, but I don't understand my mistake, and it seems my calculation is based on the condition "A wins"?

Comment: So do my example your way and confirm that you get $100\times p(A)$.  Indeed, $P(X\cap Y)$ is computed on the assumption that $Y$ occurs, just as you say.  But conditioning is more than that.  Conditioning assumes that  we are in the event space for which the probability that $Y$ occurs is $1$.

Comment: As another variant, do your problem only suppose that $B$ is using a die that only comes up $6$, though $A's$ die is fair.  Then the expected number of rounds conditioned on the event that $A$ wins, is obviously $1$ since the only way $A$ can possibly win is to throw a $6$ initially.  Your method, again, yields $\frac 16$ instead of $1$.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: @user2661923  That question clearly states that you are to work the expectation conditioned on $A$ winning.  That entails restricting the event space to those paths along which $A$ eventually wins, and dividing by the probability that $A$ eventually wins to make that a true probability space.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I made the same interpretation.  In fact, it is my oversight not realizing that therefore, you do have to divide by the probability that A wins.

Comment: @user2661923  Just to stress, the OP's computation (here) would be correct for the problem "suppose, in this game, that $A$ banks a dollar for every toss they make, but only gets to keep it if $A$ eventually wins.  What is the expected payout for $A$?"  Perfectly reasonable question...you can imagine that you have included all the paths for which $B$ wins (since $A$ gets $0$ in those cases).  But, of course, that is not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)(\tfrac 56)^{2k}\tfrac 16+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)(\tfrac 56)^{2k-1}\tfrac 16$ is the expected count for rolls until the game ends: $\mathsf E(X)$.

The first term counts rolls where the game ends on an odd roll, and the second counts rolls where the game ends on and even roll.

$$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{\{X\in2\Bbb N+1\}})+\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{\{X\in 2\Bbb N\}})\tag{Linearity}$$

So, you have evaluated: $\displaystyle\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{\{X\in2\Bbb N+1\}})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)(\tfrac 56)^{2k}\tfrac 16$

However, you want the expected count *given that* the game ends on an odd count.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X\in2\Bbb N+1) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(X~\mathbf 1_{\{X\in2\Bbb N+1\}})}{\mathsf P(X\in2\Bbb N+1)} \\[1ex] &= \dfrac{(1/6)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (2k+1)(5/6)^{2k}}{(1/6)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (5/6)^{2k}}\\[1ex] &= \dfrac{366}{121}\div\dfrac6{11}\\[1ex]&= \dfrac{61}{11}\end{align}$$